# Cómo usar el IDE de eclipse EE con jdk11 y jdk8 y crear servidor glassfish

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

os cuenta mi problema.

Tengo que descargarme el IDE de eclipse para java2ee, este:

[Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2020-09/R/eclipse-jee-2020-09-R-win32-x86_64.zip)

Para poder usar este eclipse necesito jdk11, yo lo instalo y funciona correctamente, hasta aquí no hay problema. El problema llega cuando creo un servidor Glassfish, tengo que usar jdk8, para poder usar jdk8 tengo que instalarlo, pero cuando lo instalo ya no puedo entrar a Eclipse porque me dice que solo soporta jdk11. Alguna idea?

El error que me sale es este:

> jvm is not suitable for this product eclipse version 11 or greater is
> required

Cuando creo el servidor Glassfish tiene que estar así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes instalar los JDK usando los ZIP, no los MSI. Así, puedes simplemente descomprimir cada JDK y poner los IDE/servidores a apuntar al JDK que necesites usar sin dejar nada en el PATH o en el registro de windows

Comment: Eso lo he pensado, pero de donde saco el zip del jdk8? Yo no lo encuentro.

Comment: Si no tienes un requerimiento no funcional de tu cliente (que DEBA ser Oracle Java JDK), puedes ir a cualquier compilación de OpenJDK. Yo uso y recomiendo AdoptOpenJDK, bajas la versión ZIP para windows x64 y la descomprimes y listo! Ahí también encuentras jdk11, todo libre y sin licencias comerciales nunca :)